# jQuery Datatables - Table with Subtable or Expandable Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

my code just works perfectly but in a big data with lack of usability...
My table should work with 500-600 rows (updated in every 5 seconds)...
So therefore I want to make something similar:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPKtu.png
//Buttons added via photoshop.

I can't find this functionality @jQuery.

So I want to group data under 20/25 group header.
Each IP has 60-70 row.
2 column: 
IP and FPS are the same for each group.

this is how my recent application looks like:
http://www11.pic-upload.de/03.06.14/rv6w1tboi1ip.png

so main question is: How to add Expand/collapse functionality to group of rows UNDER one main table.

and this is main part of JS code:

```
//მაგიდის ახლიდან დახატვა
function reDrawTable(){
"use strict";
$("table#content").dataTable({
    "destroy" : true,
    "ajax": "/json",
    "tableTools": true,
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "render": function (data) {
                var labelType, labelTitle;
                if (data === 1) {
                    labelTitle = "ჩართულია";
                    labelType = " alert-success";
                } else {
                    labelTitle = "გათიშულია";
                    labelType = " alert-danger";
                }
                return "<span class='label " + labelType + "'>" + labelTitle + "</span>";
            },
            "targets": 3
        }
    ]
   });
}
//მთავარი ფუნქცია
$(document).ready(function() {

//LastUpdate-ში ინახება ინფორმაციის განახლების დრო.
var table = $("table#content").dataTable(),
    lastUpdate;

//პირველი გაშვება
$.getJSON("/json", function(data){
    "use strict";
    if (data.hasOwnProperty("data") === false) {
        console.log("URL-ზე მონაცემები ცარიელია");
    }
    else {
        console.log("პირველი პროცესი");
        lastUpdate = data.lastUpdate;
        reDrawTable();
        calculateBar(data);
        search();
    }
});

//ყოველ 5 წამში ერთხელ ეშვება.
setInterval(function() {
    "use strict";
    $.getJSON("/json", function(data){
        "use strict";
        if (lastUpdate === data.lastUpdate) {
            console.log("ახალი მონაცემები არ მოიძებნა");
        } else if (data.hasOwnProperty("data") === false) {
            $("table#content").dataTable({
                "destroy" : true
            });
            console.log("მონაცემები არ იქნა მოწოდებული");
            document.getElementById("success").style.width = 0 + "%";
            document.getElementById("danger").style.width = 0 + "%";

        } else {
            reDrawTable();
            search();
            calculateBar(data);
            lastUpdate = data.lastUpdate;
            }
        });
    }, 5000);
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Moved to Ext Js 5(new beautiful UI CRISP).
The ONLY enterprise js framework.